Laravel Home Page Route Returning 404 on Localhost While Admin Routes Working Fine
I am new to laravel and am trying to get an existing laravel project to work locally on my localhost. It works perfectly fine deployed to the server but local setup is giving some issues and being new to Laravel, I have spend countless hours with no luck.
The issue I am facing is that when I run the application on localhost:8001, the main page loads to a 404 not found. but when I access a child route like localhost:8001/admin, that route loads successfully.
I notices I am unable to use the commands: php artisan route:cache and php artisan route:list return the following errors:
 LogicException 

  Unable to prepare route [admin/domain/texts] for serialization. Another route has already been assigned name [admin.custom-domain.texts].

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/AbstractRouteCollection.php:247
    243▕             $route->name($this->generateRouteName());
    244▕ 
    245▕             $this->add($route);
    246▕         } elseif (! is_null($symfonyRoutes->get($name))) {
  ➜ 247▕             throw new LogicException("Unable to prepare route [{$route->uri}] for serialization. Another route has already been assigned name [{$name}].");
    248▕         }
    249▕ 
    250▕         $symfonyRoutes->add($route->getName(), $route->toSymfonyRoute());
    251▕ 


php artisan route:list
 Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException 

  

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:1144
    1140▕      */
    1141▕     public function abort($code, $message = '', array $headers = [])
    1142▕     {
    1143▕         if ($code == 404) {
  ➜ 1144▕             throw new NotFoundHttpException($message);
    1145▕         }
    1146▕ 
    1147▕         throw new HttpException($code, $message, null, $headers);
    1148▕     }

      +1 vendor frames 
  2   app/Http/Helpers/Helper.php:540
      abort()

  3   app/Http/Controllers/UserFront/FrontendController.php:50


My root .htaaccess is:
ErrorDocument 403 https://%{HTTP_HOST}/404
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ server.php
</IfModule>

My public .htaaccess is:
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
  </IfModule>

  RewriteEngine On

  # Handle Authorization Header
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
  RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

  # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
  RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

  # Send Requests To Front Controller...
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

my admin.php is:
 Route::group(['middleware' => 'checkpermission:Custom Domains'], function () {
        Route::get('/domains', [CustomDomainController::class, 'index'])->name('admin.custom-domain.index');
        Route::get('/domain/texts', [CustomDomainController::class, 'texts'])->name('admin.custom-domain.texts');
        Route::post('/domain/texts', [CustomDomainController::class, 'updateTexts'])->name('admin.custom-domain.texts');
        Route::post('/domain/status', [CustomDomainController::class, 'status'])->name('admin.custom-domain.status');
        Route::post('/domain/mail', [CustomDomainController::class, 'mail'])->name('admin.custom-domain.mail');
        Route::post('/domain/delete', [CustomDomainController::class, 'delete'])->name('admin.custom-domain.delete');
        Route::post('/domain/bulk-delete', [CustomDomainController::class, 'bulkDelete'])->name('admin.custom-domain.bulk.delete');
    });

I have tried clearing php artisan and clearing the cache with no luck. I have tried changing access in the .htaaccess but still same issue and researched through all the limited articles on this matter.
FrontEndController:
public function __construct()
    {

        $user = getUser();
        $currentLang = $this->getUserCurrentLanguage($user);
        $be = BasicExtended::query()
            ->where('user_id', $user->id)
            ->where('language_id', $currentLang->id)
            ->first();


        if (!empty($be['pusher_app_id']) && !empty($be['pusher_app_key']) && !empty($be['pusher_app_secret']) && !empty($be['pusher_app_cluster'])) {

            $pusherCredentials = [
                'driver' => 'pusher',
                'app_id' => $be['pusher_app_id'],
                'key' => $be['pusher_app_key'],
                'secret' => $be['pusher_app_secret'],
                'options' => [
                    'cluster' => $be['pusher_app_cluster'],
                ],
            ];

            Config::set('broadcasting.connections.pusher', $pusherCredentials);
        }
    }

    public function offlinePWA($domain)
    {
        return view('user-front.offline');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $user = getUser();
        $feature = UserPermissionHelper::packagePermission($user->id);
        $feature = json_decode($feature, true);

        $currentLang = $this->getUserCurrentLanguage($user);
        $lang_id = $currentLang->id;
        $bs = BasicSetting::query()
            ->where('user_id', $user->id)
            ->where('language_id', $currentLang->id)
            ->first();
        $currentTheme = $bs->theme;

        $be = BasicExtended::query()
            ->where('user_id', $user->id)
            ->where('language_id', $currentLang->id)
            ->first();
        $pwaData = json_decode($user->pwa, true);

        if (in_array('Amazon AWS s3', $feature)) {

            $pwaData = json_decode($user->pwa, true);
            if ($pwaData) {
                $pwaData['start_url'] = url()->current();
                foreach ($pwaData['icons'] as $key => $icon) {

                    $awsImg = Uploader::getImageUrl(public_path('assets/pwa'), $icon['src'], $bs);
                    $pwaData['icons'][$key]['src'] = $awsImg;
                }
                file_put_contents(public_path('assets/pwa/manifest.json'), json_encode($pwaData));
            }
        } else {
            $pwaData['start_url'] = url()->current();

            file_put_contents(public_path('assets/pwa/manifest.json'), json_encode($pwaData));
        }

        $data['sliders'] = Slider::query()
            ->where('language_id', $lang_id)
            ->where('user_id', $user->id)
            ->orderBy('serial_number', 'ASC')
            ->get();
        $data['features'] = Feature::query()
            ->where('language_id', $lang_id)
            ->where('user_id', $user->id)
            ->get();
        $data['intro_feature_items'] = IntroPoint::query()
            ->where('language_id', $lang_id)
            ->where('user_id', $user->id)
            ->get();
        $data['sectionHeading'] = UserSectionHeading::query()
            ->where('language_id', $lang_id)
            ->where('user_id', $user->id)
            ->first();
        $data['members'] = Member::query()
            ->where('language_id', $lang_id)
            ->where('feature', 1)
            ->where('user_id', $user->id)->take(3)
            ->get();
        $data['testimonials'] = Testimonial::query()
            ->where('language_id', $lang_id)
            ->where('user_id', $user->id)
            ->orderBy('serial_number', 'ASC')
            ->get();
        $data['blogs'] = Blog::query()
            ->join('user_blog_informations', 'user_blogs.id', '=', 'user_blog_informations.blog_id')
            ->where('user_blog_informations.language_id', '=', $lang_id)
            ->where('user_blog_informations.user_id', '=', $user->id)
            ->select(
                'user_blogs.image',
                'user_blogs.created_at',
                'user_blog_informations.title',
                'user_blog_informations.slug',
                'user_blogs.id',
                'user_blog_informations.content',
                'user_blog_informations.author'
            )
            ->orderByDesc('user_blogs.id')
            ->limit(3)
            ->get();
        $data['special_product'] = Product::query()
            ->join('product_informations', 'products.id', 'product_informations.product_id')
            ->where('status', 1)
            ->where('is_special', 1)
            ->where('products.user_id', $user->id)
            ->where('product_informations.language_id', $lang_id)
            ->orderBy('products.id', 'desc')
            ->get();
        $data['categories'] = Pcategory::query()
            ->where('status', 1)
            ->where('is_feature', 1)
            ->where('language_id', $currentLang->id)
            ->where('user_id', $user->id)
            ->get();

        $data['products'] = Product::query()
            ->join('product_informations', 'products.id', 'product_informations.product_id')
            ->where('status', 1)
            ->where('products.user_id', $user->id)
            ->where('product_informations.language_id', $lang_id)
            ->paginate(10);
        if ($bs->home_version == 'slider') {
            $data['shapeImg'] = $be->slider_shape_img ?? null;
            $data['bottomImg'] = $be->slider_bottom_img ?? null;
        } else {
            $data['shapeImg'] = $be->hero_shape_img ?? null;
            $data['bottomImg'] = $be->hero_bottom_img ?? null;
        }



        $features = LimitCheckerHelper::getPackageSelectedData($user->id, 'features');
        $data['packageFeatures'] = json_decode($features->features, true);

        if ($currentTheme == "fastfood") {
            return view('user-front.fastfood.index', $data);
        } elseif ($currentTheme == "bakery") {
            return view('user-front.bakery.index', $data);
        } elseif ($currentTheme == "pizza") {
            return view('user-front.pizza.index', $data);
        } elseif ($currentTheme == "coffee") {
            return view('user-front.coffee.index', $data);
        } elseif ($currentTheme == "medicine") {
            return view('user-front.medicine.index', $data);
        } elseif ($currentTheme == "grocery") {
            return view('user-front.grocery.index', $data);
        } elseif ($currentTheme == "beverage") {
            return view('user-front.beverage.index', $data);
        }
    }

    public function about_us()
    {
        $user = getUser();
        $feature = UserPermissionHelper::packagePermission($user->id);
        $feature = json_decode($feature, true);

        $currentLang = $this->getUserCurrentLanguage($user);
        $lang_id = $currentLang->id;

        $data['sectionHeading'] = UserSectionHeading::query()
            ->where('language_id', $lang_id)
            ->where('user_id', $user->id)
            ->first();
        $data['members'] = Member::query()
            ->where('language_id', $lang_id)
            ->where('feature', 1)
            ->where('user_id', $user->id)->take(3)
            ->get();
        $data['testimonials'] = Testimonial::query()
            ->where('language_id', $lang_id)
            ->where('user_id', $user->id)
            ->orderBy('serial_number', 'ASC')
            ->get();


        $features = LimitCheckerHelper::getPackageSelectedData($user->id, 'features');
        $data['packageFeatures'] = json_decode($features->features, true);

        return view('user-front.fastfood.about_us', $data);
    }

    public function subscribe(Request $request, $domain)
    {
        $user = getUser();
        $currentLang = $this->getUserCurrentLanguage($user);
        $keywords = json_decode($currentLang->keywords, true);

        $rules = [
            'email' => ['required', function ($attribute, $value, $fail) use ($user, $keywords) {
                $subscriber = Subscriber::query()
                    ->where([
                        ['email', $value],
                        ['user_id', $user->id]
                    ])->get();
                if ($subscriber->count() > 0) {
                    Session::flash('error', $keywords['This email is already subscribed'] ?? 'This email is already subscribed');
                    $fail($keywords['attribute already subscribed for this user'] ?? ':attribute already subscribed for this user');
                }
            }]
        ];
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json(array('errors' => $validator->getMessageBag()->toArray()));
        }
        $subsc = new Subscriber;
        $subsc->email = $request->email;
        $subsc->user_id = $user->id;
        $subsc->save();
        return "success";
    }

    public function reservationForm($domain)
    {
        $user = getUser();
        $currentLang = $this->getUserCurrentLanguage($user);
        $bs = $currentLang->basic_setting;
        if ($bs->is_quote == 0) {
            return view('errors.user-404');
        }
        $data['inputs'] = ReservationInput::query()
            ->where('language_id', $currentLang->id)
            ->where('user_id', $user->id)
            ->orderBy('order_number', 'ASC')
            ->with('reservation_input_options')
            ->get();
        if ($bs->is_quote == 1) {
            return view('user-front.fastfood.reservation', $data);
        }
    }

    public function tableBook(Request $request)
    {
        $user = getUser();
        $currentLang = $this->getUserCurrentLanguage($user);
        $keywords = json_decode($currentLang->keywords, true);

        $count = LimitCheckerHelper::getTableReservationCount($user->id);
        $package = LimitCheckerHelper::currentMembershipPackage($user->id);
        $membership = LimitCheckerHelper::currentMembership($user->id);

        if (is_null($package) ||  $count >= $package->table_reservation_limit) {

            return back()->with('error', "we are currently unable to receive any reservation")->withInput($request->all());
        }

        $currentLang = $this->getUserCurrentLanguage($user);

        $bs = BasicSetting::query()
            ->where('user_id', $user->id)
            ->where('language_id', $currentLang->id)
            ->first();

        $reservation_inputs = $currentLang->reservation_inputs;

        $messages = [
            'g-recaptcha-response.required' => 'Please verify that you are not a robot.',
            'g-recaptcha-response.captcha' => 'Captcha error! try again later or contact site admin.',
        ];

        $rules = [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
        ];

        foreach ($reservation_inputs as $input) {
            if ($input->required == 1) {
                $rules["$input->name"] = 'required';
            }
        }

        if ($bs->is_recaptcha == 1 && empty($request->type)) {
            $rules['g-recaptcha-response'] = 'required|captcha';
        }

        $request->validate($rules, $messages);

        $fields = [];
        foreach ($reservation_inputs as $input) {
            $in_name = $input->name;
            if ($request["$in_name"]) {
                $fields["$in_name"] = $request["$in_name"];
            }
        }
        $jsonfields = json_encode($fields);
        $jsonfields = str_replace("\/", "/", $jsonfields);

        $data = new TableBook;
        $data->name = $request->name;
        $data->email = $request->email;
        $data->fields = $jsonfields;
        $data->user_id = $user->id;
        $data->membership_id = $membership->id;
        $data->save();

        $mailer = new MegaMailer();

        $data['toMail'] = $user->email;
        $data['toName'] = $user->username;

        $data['fullname'] = $request->name;
        $data['email'] = $request->email;
        $data['subject'] = 'Table Reservation Request';
        $data['body'] = "<p><strong>You have received a new table reservation request</strong></p>  <p><strong>Name:</strong> $request->name </p><p><strong>Email:</strong> $request->email </p>";

        $mailer->mailContactMessage($data);

        Session::flash('success', $keywords['Reservation request sent successfully. We will contact you soon.'] ?? 'Reservation request sent successfully. We will contact you soon.');
        return back();
    }

    // blog section start
    public function blogs(Request $request, $domain)
    {
        $user = getUser();
        $currentLang = $this->getUserCurrentLanguage($user);
        $data['currentLang'] = $currentLang;
        $lang_id = $currentLang->id;
        $category = $request->category;

        if (!empty($category)) {
            $data['category'] = BlogCategory::query()
                ->where('user_id', $user->id)
                ->findOrFail($category);
        }
        $term = $request->term;

        $data['bcats'] = BlogCategory::query()
            ->where('user_id', $user->id)
            ->where('language_id', $lang_id)
            ->where('status', 1)
            ->orderBy('serial_number', 'ASC')
            ->get();

        $data['blogs'] = Blog::query()->join('user_blog_informations', 'user_blogs.id', '=', 'user_blog_informations.blog_id')
            ->where('user_blog_informations.language_id', '=', $lang_id)
            ->where('user_blog_informations.user_id', '=', $user->id)
            ->select('user_blogs.image', 'user_blogs.created_at', 'user_blog_informations.title', 'user_blog_informations.slug', 'user_blogs.id', 'user_blog_informations.content', 'user_blog_informations.blog_category_id', 'user_blog_informations.language_id')
            ->when($category, function ($query, $category) {
                return $query->where('blog_category_id', $category);
            })->when($term, function ($query, $term) {
                return $query->where('title', 'like', '%' . $term . '%');
            })->when($currentLang, function ($query, $currentLang) {
                return $query->where('language_id', $currentLang->id);
            })
            ->orderBy('serial_number', 'ASC')
            ->paginate(9);
        return view('user-front.fastfood.blogs', $data);
    }

    public function blogDetails($domain, $slug, $id)
    {

        $user = getUser();

        $currentLang = $this->getUserCurrentLanguage($user);
        $lang_id = $currentLang->id;
        $data['blog'] = Blog::query()
            ->join('user_blog_informations', 'user_blogs.id', '=', 'user_blog_informations.blog_id')
            ->where('user_blog_informations.language_id', '=', $lang_id)
            ->where('user_blog_informations.user_id', '=', $user->id)
            ->select(
                'user_blogs.image',
                'user_blogs.created_at',
                'user_blog_informations.title',
                'user_blog_informations.slug',
                'user_blogs.id',
                'user_blog_informations.content',
                'user_blog_informations.blog_category_id',
                'user_blog_informations.language_id'
            )
            ->findOrFail($id);
        $data['bcats'] = BlogCategory::query()
            ->where('status', 1)
            ->where('language_id', $lang_id)
            ->where('user_id', $user->id)
            ->orderBy('serial_number', 'ASC')
            ->get();
        return view('user-front.fastfood.blog-details', $data);
    }

    public function contact($domain)
    {
        $user = getUser();
        $currentLang = $this->getUserCurrentLanguage($user);
        $data['contact'] = BasicSetting::query()
            ->where('language_id', $currentLang->id)
            ->where('user_id', $user->id)
            ->select(
                'contact_form_title',
                'contact_info_title',
                'contact_address',
                'contact_number',
                'contact_text'
            )->first();

        return view('user-front.fastfood.contact', $data);
    }

    public function sendmail(Request $request)
    {
        $user = getUser();
        $currentLang = $this->getUserCurrentLanguage($user);
        $keywords = json_decode($currentLang->keywords, true);
        $userBs = $currentLang->basic_setting;
        $messages = [
            'g-recaptcha-response.required' => 'Please verify that you are not a robot.',
            'g-recaptcha-response.captcha' => 'Captcha error! try again later or contact site admin.',
        ];
        $rules = [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'subject' => 'required',
            'message' => 'required'
        ];

        if ($userBs->is_recaptcha == 1) {
            $rules['g-recaptcha-response'] = 'required|captcha';
        }

        $request->validate($rules, $messages);

        $toUser = getUser();
        $data['toMail'] = $toUser->email;
        $data['toName'] = $toUser->username;
        $data['subject'] = $request->subject;
        $data['body'] = "<div>$request->message</div><br>
                         <strong>To contact further with the enquirer please use the below information:</strong><br>
                         <strong>Enquirer Name:</strong> $request->name <br>
                         <strong>Enquirer Mail:</strong> $request->email <br>
                         ";
        $data['fullname'] = $request->name;
        $data['email'] = $request->email;
        $mailer = new MegaMailer();
        $mailer->mailContactMessage($data);
        Session::flash('success', $keywords['Email sent successfully!'] ?? 'Email sent successfully!');
        return back();
    }


    public function career(Request $request, $domain)
    {
        $user = getUser();
        $currentLang = $this->getUserCurrentLanguage($user);
        $data['jcats'] = $currentLang->job_categories()
            ->where('status', 1)
            ->where('user_id', $user->id)
            ->orderBy('serial_number', 'ASC')
            ->get();
        $category = $request->category;
        $term = $request->term;
        if (!empty($category)) {
            $data['category'] = Jcategory::query()
                ->where('user_id', $user->id)
                ->findOrFail($category);
        }
        $data['jobs'] = Job::query()
            ->where('user_id', $user->id)
            ->when($category, function ($query, $category) {
                return $query->where('jcategory_id', $category);
            })->when($term, function ($query, $term) {
                return $query->where('title', 'like', '%' . $term . '%');
            })->when($currentLang, function ($query, $currentLang) {
                return $query->where('language_id', $currentLang->id);
            })
            ->orderBy('serial_number', 'ASC')
            ->paginate(4);

        $data['jobscount'] = Job::query()
            ->where('user_id', $user->id)
            ->when($currentLang, function ($query, $currentLang) {
                return $query->where('language_id', $currentLang->id);
            })->count();

        return view('user-front.fastfood.career', $data);
    }


    public function careerDetails($domain, $slug, $id)
    {
        $user = getUser();
        $currentLang = $this->getUserCurrentLanguage($user);
        $data['jcats'] = $currentLang->job_categories()
            ->where('status', 1)
            ->where('user_id', $user->id)
            ->orderBy('serial_number', 'ASC')
            ->get();
        $data['job'] = Job::query()
            ->where('user_id', $user->id)
            ->findOrFail($id);
        $data['jobscount'] = Job::query()
            ->where('user_id', $user->id)
            ->when($currentLang, function ($query, $currentLang) {
                return $query->where('language_id', $currentLang->id);
            })->count();
        return view('user-front.fastfood.career-details', $data);
    }

    public function gallery($domain)
    {
        $user = getUser();
        $currentLang = $this->getUserCurrentLanguage($user);
        $lang_id = $currentLang->id;
        $data['galleries'] = Gallery::query()
            ->where('user_id', $user->id)
            ->where('language_id', $lang_id)
            ->orderBy('serial_number', 'ASC')
            ->get();
        return view('user-front.fastfood.gallery', $data);
    }

    public function faq($domain)
    {
        $user = getUser();
        $currentLang = $this->getUserCurrentLanguage($user);
        $lang_id = $currentLang->id;
        $data['faqs'] = Faq::query()
            ->where('user_id', $user->id)
            ->where('language_id', $lang_id)
            ->orderBy('serial_number', 'ASC')
            ->get();
        return view('user-front.fastfood.faq', $data);
    }

    public function team($domain)
    {
        $user = getUser();
        $currentLang = $this->getUserCurrentLanguage($user);
        $data['members'] = Member::query()
            ->when($currentLang, function ($query, $currentLang) use ($user) {
                return $query->where('language_id', $currentLang->id)
                    ->where('user_id', $user->id);
            })->get();
        return view('user-front.fastfood.teams', $data);
    }
        
//some more code here
 
}

it is complaining on line 50 which is: $user = getUser();
and the getUser() is in the htlper.php:
if (!function_exists('getUser')) {

    function getUser()
    {
        $parsedUrl = parse_url(url()->current());

        $host =  $parsedUrl['host'];


        // if the current URL contains the website domain
        if (str_contains($host, env('WEBSITE_HOST'))) {
            $host = str_replace('www.', '', $host);
            // if current URL is a path based URL
            if ($host == env('WEBSITE_HOST')) {
                $path = explode('/', $parsedUrl['path']);
                $username = $path[1];
            }
            // if the current URL is a subdomain
            else {
                $hostArr = explode('.', $host);
                $username = $hostArr[0];
            }

            if (($host == $username . '.' . env('WEBSITE_HOST')) || ($host . '/' == env('WEBSITE_HOST') . '/')) {
                $user = User::query()
                    ->where('username', $username)
                    ->where('online_status', 1)
                    ->where('status', 1)
                    ->whereHas('memberships', function ($q) {
                        $q->where('status', '=', 1)
                            ->where('start_date', '<=', Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d'))
                            ->where('expire_date', '>=', Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d'));
                    })->first();

                if (empty($user)) {
                    abort(404);
                }

                // if the current url is a subdomain
                if ($host != env('WEBSITE_HOST')) {
                    if (!cPackageHasSubdomain($user)) {
                        return view('errors.404');
                    }
                }

                return $user;
            }
        }

        // Always include 'www.' at the beginning of host
        if (!str_starts_with($host, 'www.')) {
            $host = 'www.' . $host;
        }


        $user = User::where('online_status', 1)
            ->whereHas('custom_domains', function ($q) use ($host) {
                $q->where('status', '=', 1)
                    ->where(function ($query) use ($host) {
                        $query->where('requested_domain', '=', $host)
                            ->orWhere('requested_domain', '=', str_replace("www.", "", $host));
                    });
                // fetch the custom domain , if it matches 'with www.' URL or 'without www.' URL
            })
            ->whereHas('memberships', function ($q) {
                $q->where('status', '=', 1)
                    ->where('start_date', '<=', Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d'))
                    ->where('expire_date', '>=', Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d'));
            })->first();

        if (empty($user)) {
            abort(404);
        }
        if (!cPackageHasCdomain($user)) {
            return view('errors.404');
        }

        return $user;
    }
}


For the admin.custom-domain.texts, check your routes/admin.php, you have 2 routes with the same name somewhere

I have updated my post to add that. the 2 requests are get and post so they arnt duplicate.

The names are. Even if they're two different methods, they still need two different names.

As for route:list, can you show the relevant code around app/Http/Controllers/UserFront/FrontendController.php:50 as well as the help function it's trying to use there?

@aynber, I have updated the question with the requested information.

although i got it loaded, tenant routes aren't working. also i still get the error when running php artisan route:list.

You're calling $user = getUser(); in the __construct() function, which means it will run every time things are loaded, such as during route:list. However, since it's being accessed through the API, $host would be empty, causing $user to most likely be null, and it throws a 404. You may need to add something to check if it's being accessed through the command line or web.

The user is returned upon inspecting further. can it be an issue with the .htaaccess? The whole application works just the tenant subdomain and route based page arnt.

The user is returned when it's a web user, but there is no user to return when you run any cli commands, like route:list, so it throws that error.

Turns out my .env file had theWEBSITE_HOST=http://127.0.0.1:8000 changing it to WEBSITE_HOST=http://127.0.0.1worked.
